# Not quite understanding MPI

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, thread-safety, mpi

I am attempting to make a program using MPI that will find the value of PI using MPI.

Currently I can find the sum this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define NUMSTEPS 1000000

int main() {
        int i;
        double x, pi, sum = 0.0;
        struct timespec start, end;

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
        double step = 1.0/(double) NUMSTEPS;
        x = 0.5 * step;

        for (i=0;i<= NUMSTEPS; i++){
                x+=step;
                sum += 4.0/(1.0+x*x);
        }
        pi = step * sum;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
        u_int64_t diff = 1000000000L * (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;

        printf("PI is %.20f\n",pi);
        printf("elapsed time = %llu nanoseconds\n", (long long unsigned int) diff);

        return 0;
}
```

But this does not use MPI.

So I have tried to make my own in MPI.  My logic is:

1. Split the 1000000 into equal parts based on how many processors I have
2. Calculate the values for each range
3. Send the calculated value back to the master and then divide by the number of processors.  I would like to keep the main thread free and not do any work.  Similar to a master-slave system.

Here's what I have currently.  This doesn't seem to be working and the send/receive gives errors about incompatible variables for receive and send.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define NUMSTEPS 1000000


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int  comm_sz; //number of processes
    int  my_rank; //my process rank

    // Initialize the MPI environment
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_sz);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

    // Get the name of the processor
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    int name_len;
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);

    // Slaves
    if (my_rank != 0) {
        
    // Process math then send 
    
    int i;
        double x, pi, sum = 0.0;

        double step = 1.0/(double) NUMSTEPS;
        x = 0.5 * step;

    // Find the start and end for the number
    int processors = comm_sz - 1;
    
    int thread_multi = NUMSTEPS / processors;
        
    int start = my_rank * thread_multi;
        
    if((my_rank - 1) != 0){
        start += 1;
    }
    
    int end = start + thread_multi ;
    
        for (i=start; i <= end; i++){
                x+=step;
                sum += 4.0 / (1.0 + x * x);
        }
        pi = step * sum;
        
        
    MPI_Send(pi, 1.0, MPI_DOUBLE 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        
    // Master
    } else {
        // Things in here only get called once.
        double pi = 0.0;
        double total = 0.0;
            for (int q = 1; q < comm_sz; q++) {
                MPI_Recv(pi, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, q, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
                total += pi;
        pi = 0.0;
            }
        
        // Take the added totals and divide by amount of processors that processed, to get the average
        double finished = total / (comm_sz - 1);
        
        // Print sum here
        printf("Pi Is: %d", finished);
    }
    // Finalize the MPI environment.
    MPI_Finalize();
    
}
```

I've currently spent around 3 hours working on this.  Never used MPI.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Compare your arguments to the doc for MPI_Send https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v4.1/man3/MPI_Send.3.php

Comment: The communication pattern is a textbook example for `MPI_Reduce()`. Also, it is simple and more efficient if the master makes its fair share of work instead of waiting.

Answer (score 2):

Try compiling with more compiler warnings and try to fix them, for instance `-Wall -Wextra` should give you excellent clues about what the issues are.

According to [MPI_Send documentation](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Send.html) the first argument is a pointer, so you seem to be ignoring an automatic "conversion to pointer" error. You have the same issue in the `MPI_Recv()` call.

You can try to pass `pi` as `&pi` in `MPI_Recv` and `MPI_Send` and check if that fixes the error.

As a comment, you can declare dummy variables as `pi` as a local variables inside the master loop to avoid side-effects:

```
for (int q = 1; q < comm_sz; q++) {
    double pi = 0;
    MPI_Recv(&pi, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, q, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    total += pi;
}
```